# USB Drive doesn't mount

Tags: usb, mount

I've got a USB flash drive which doesn't mount. It was so far only used on Windows Computer and there the user gets the message that you have to format it in order to use it correctly.

I plugged the drive in my computer and it doesn't mount. Using `sudo fdisk -l` gives me the output:

`Disk /dev/sdc: 7839 MB, 7839154176 bytes
242 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1020 cylinders, total 15310848 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000`

`Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table`

I tried to mount it with `mount`, but that doesn't work as well.

I know there are some files on the drive, therefore is it possible to recover them or do I just have to format the whole drive in order to use it again?

Answer (score 0):

This:

> Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

... tells that there isn't likely to be any software that can "mount" the flash drive.

If you are sure there should be data on it; the disk recovery software is the only option.
Names to look for `testdisk` and `photorec` - there are a lot more to try out, google for it.